# NHibernate - How do I delete a child entity in a bidirectional relationship?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I've been searching around and found some possible solutions, but none with any result. I'll try to explain as good as I can.

I have two models, PostModel (parent) and CommentModel (child). For better understanding, my mapping looks like this:

Mapping for Post:

```
public class PostMap : ClassMap<PostModel> 
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        // Table
        Table("Post");

        // Relations
        HasMany<CommentModel>(o => o.Comments).KeyColumn("PostId").Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

Mapping for comment:

```
public class CommentMap : ClassMap<CommentModel> 
{
    public CommentMap()
    {
        // Table
        Table("Comment");

        // References
        References<PostModel>(o => o.Post).Column("PostId");
    }
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is to delete a comment entity from post like this:

```
public void DeleteComment(CommentModel commentToDelete) 
{
    // Delete from list
    commentToDelete.Post.Comments.Remove(commentToDelete);

    // Update parent
    Update(commentToDelete.Post);
}
```

The result? Nothing is happening. Nothing is deleted from the list, no exceptions or what so ever. Does anyone have a solution for this, or any thoughts? I really appreciate all help I can get.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set Inverse() you will have to update your comment

I suggest this approach:

```
public void DeleteComment(CommentModel commentToDelete) 
{
    // Delete from list
    commentToDelete.Post.Comments.Remove(commentToDelete);

    // This is needed because the Comments is an Inverse collection
    commentToDelete.Post = null;

    // Update parent
    Update(commentToDelete.Post);

    // Delete the comment
    Delete(commentToDelete);
}
```

If you always remove your associations in both objects, you should not have problems.

You can also remove the Inverse

```
HasMany<CommentModel>(o => o.Comments).KeyColumn("PostId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Comment: When I set Post = null I get exception "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999". But that is probably because I have a Datetime property?

Comment: Yeah maybe and it tries to set it to DateTime.MinValue, in fact DateTime.MinValue is smaller than the min datetime value supported by SQL Server. You should look at the properties in the commentToDelete object. And maybe you could Delete the record instead of updating it, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh I did't know that! Anyway, I tried your example and I tried setting my datetime property to current date, but then it just complain about another property that is NULL. It feels like it fails to update because Post is.. yeah, NULL :)

Comment: I found what was causing this error, see my post. Although I'm pretty sure your example is working just fine aswell, so I'm marking that as the correct answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was causing this kind of error and for me it was a manipulation of the CommentList in my PostModel.

I ended up doing this and it works perfectly:

```
public void DeleteComment(CommentModel commentToDelete) 
{
    // Delete from list
    commentToDelete.Post.Comments.Remove(commentToDelete);

    // Update parent
    Update(commentToDelete.Post);
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at the records in your database, I think the relationship must have been deleted but the Comment will maybe be hanging in your comments table.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked and the comment was deleted. I don't know how it works, but it works!